# how to check if running through specific ManagedExecutor

Tags: quarkus

I have to run certain tasks for users in sequential manner. To achieve this I create a map where keys are user ids and values are ManagedExecutors created like this:

```
        ManagedExecutor managedExecutor = ((SmallRyeManagedExecutor.Builder)ManagedExecutor.builder())
            .propagated(ThreadContext.ALL_REMAINING)
            .maxAsync(1)
            .maxQueued(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
            .withExecutorService(parentManagedExecutor)
            .build();
```

And when I need to run a task I get from this map managed executor and execute task on it.

Now in certain parts of code run through this managed executors I would like to know if current thread is really called through one of this managed executors and what user id is associated with it.

Is this possible and how to implement it?

Comment: Why exactly do you need to know which executor is running your threads?

Comment: @geoand I want to add a check to make sure this parts of code run only in this executor assigned to correct userId. And throw exceptions if it's not the case, otherwise we usually find bugs only during production runtime.

Comment: I don't see anything in the API (or the implementation) that would give you such information